# Laravel How to get Helper function return value in controller as url path

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-helper

I have created a laravel helper something like this which generates an sql file in /sql/ under my database folder location so database/sqls/xxxxx.sql

```
 class Helpsql { 


public function cd(string $file = '')
        {

            $destinationFile = 'mysql';

            $destinationPath = database_path(sprintf('sql/', $destinationFile));

            $this->callerPassthrough('info', 'create file');

            return $destinationPath;
        }
}
```

I create a controller function like this
AbcController.php

```
public function index(){
$urlpath = new Helpsql;
$urlpath->cd();
return response()->download($destinationPath);
}
```

My route is:
Route::get('path', 'AbcController@index');

but it is not returning the path to download the file.

Comment: Do you mean to return them to your view?

Comment: no. in controller

Answer (score 1):

Try return from your controller this response:

`return response()->download($destinationPath);`

Comment: should i create $var = new Helpsql() and then return response()->download($destinationPath); ??

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing any variable data to

> $urlpath->cd();

and

> $destinationPath

variable is undefined, you have not set any data to it.

It should be this:

```
public function index(){
$urlpath = new Helpsql;
return response()->download($urlpath->cd()); 
}
```

Comment: i dont need some data.. i need $destinationPath in return as url

Comment: You have a variable called $file that is blank in your cd() method. You are not setting it, so $destinationFile will always be blank. Also the cd() method returns data, not the variable name $destinationPath

Comment: Yes, because you are not passing any data to $file when you are calling cd() method.

Comment: so how should i write?

Comment: Where are you doing dd()?

Comment: in the helper function.

Comment: Then use this return response()->download($urlpath->cd());

Comment: Then you have a problem with your cd() method.